# JAVA FileNotFoundException when using command line

Tags: java

I have a swing application that accesses a text file via a BufferedReader.
When I run it in NetBeans, the file is accessed fine. But, when I run the jar file itself from the command line, I get a FileNotFoundException.

I am using a FileInputStream, and initializing it with a path to the text file:
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("appsDB/Apps.txt");

The appsDB folder is at the same level as the src folder, and so I'm guessing that's why the path works and the text file is found when I run it in NetBeans. What do I need to do differently, should I be specifying the path to the Apps.txt file differently?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the jar from the directory that contains the appsDB directory

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your assumption is correct. If possible, add the file to your src/somefolder folder and access it using getClass().getResourceAsStream("/somefolder/somefile")